# Create folders using each line of text file. Line1 = folder1, etc

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a Windows 2008 server. I am extracting a txt file containing a list of users from an SQL table:

USER1
USER2
USER3
...

and I need to create folders using each username from that list (that can vary), and then copy data from a unique source folder into each one of those folders. 
I am able to create variables var1, var2, etc...using help from another answered question here but I do not know how to use those into my folder test and creation function.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (mysourcefile.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var
```

But this fails miserably:

```
IF exist %var% (echo %var% exists ) ELSE ( mkdir %var% && echo %var% created )
```

This might be very simple but after many tries I am now lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the text file is just the list of usernames, you can do this.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (mysourcefile.txt) do (
    if exist "%%~A" ( echo %%A exists ) else ( md %%A && echo %%A created )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: I was trying using Powershell (it was kind of working), but your solution works right away and fits better in my environment. Thank you!